# Using Images from the Web for personal use

Tags: copyright

I would like to include images from the web on my personal website(non-profit & non-commercial use), how do I say that the images are not mine and they belong to their respective owners? does this relate to this

"Copyright Disclaimer Under Section 107 of the Copyright Act 1976, allowance is made for 'fair use' for purposes such as criticism, comment, news reporting, teaching, scholarship, and research. Fair use is a use permitted by copyright statute that might otherwise be infringing. Non-profit, educational or personal use tips the balance in favor of fair use."

Comment: Non-profit does not equal fair use.

Comment: Are you looking for a disclaimer like [no theft intended](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m-KLAqyUg20)?

Answer (score 3):

Simply admitting that the images are not yours does not give you the right to use them. The fact that you are not profitting from them does not change this.

There is no magical statement or disclaimer that will change this.

**If** your use of the images constitutes Fair Use (since you're not mentioning how you're using them, **it probably doesn't**), you can include a fair use disclaimer. Sample dislaimers can be found online.

A disclaimer should include the following:

- A statement that the work in question is not yours
- That the use falls under Fair Use and **why**
- Section 107 of the copyright act